# Burninate the [options] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The tag has currently <del>867</del> 894 questions most of which are regarding options in various tools, compiler, languages, ...

It'd be rather useful on https://money.stackexchange.com/ or even https://quant.stackexchange.com/ but seems to of little value on StackOverflow.

Could we burninate [options](/questions/tagged/options)?  The questions appear to be used in context of a programming language or compiler, so it seems that retagging shouldn't be needed.

Comment: +1. On SO it's a meta-tag; just look at it's tag wiki excerpt: "Options are various choices or courses of action available to someone in a particular situation."

Comment: Have you determined if any questions using it will need a retag?

Comment: @slugster I haven't looked at all the questions, but it doesn't seem like that those would need a retag.  All these seem to be used in one context or the other, e.g. JDK, android, jquery, php, batch-file, bash, wordpress, ruby, grails, css, c++, java, magento, jsp, html, scala ...